# variabled passed through async function is changing when i call it twice

Tags: javascript

i have an async httprequest seen below

```
function httpGet(URL, type, daily, weekly, monthly)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            if (type == 'table')
            {
                createTable(xmlhttp.responseText, daily, weekly, monthly);
            }       
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
    xmlhttp.send();    
}
```

When i call it twice for example

```
httpGet('example', 'table', 1, 2, 3);
httpGet('example2', 'table', 4, 5, 6);
```

They will both return the results from the second URL. Im sure making the function not async will fix this but thats not very user friendly either.

Is there anyway to set in stone the url i want to return as the one passed in the parameter that originally called it instead of last called it

Comment: `They will both return the results from the second URL` But the function currently doesn't "return" anything.

Comment: Sorry i should rephrase, it will run the createTable function with the response text returned from the second URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't declaring `xmlhttp` with `const`, `let`, or `var` - this means that it will be a global variable, so each call to `httpGet` will result in the *reassignment* of the global variable, rather than each function having a separate binding for `xmlhttp`. So, when the last line in there runs:

```
createTable(xmlhttp.responseText, daily, weekly, monthly);
```

the `xmlhttp` there will always be referring to the *final* `xmlhttp`.

Change your code to:

```
function httpGet(URL, type, daily, weekly, monthly) {
  const xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest
    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
    : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // ...
```

to ensure that each call gets a separate binding of `xmlhttp`.

Also, you might consider using `fetch` and ditching `ActiveXObject` - `ActiveXObject` should only be needed for supporting IE6 and below, which are broken browsers that probably shouldn't be considered at all.